# Does my PRV need to be replaced?

Tags: water, water-pressure

What is an acceptable pressure drop when a faucet is opened, if the PRV is functioning correctly and all the pipes are sized right? I have a 1.25” supply transitioning to a 1” and then splitting into two 3/4” lines for the hose bibs The pressure gauge at the hose bib reads 65 psi with no water running. When I open a hose bib next to the one being monitored, the pressure drops to 40 psi.  I see drops of 20-24 psi, even when if I were to open  a faucet in the home instead.

Thanks for any pointers.

Sam

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on the system most pressure reducing valves or regulators are there to prevent problems on the customer side , 60-80 psi is normal and most faucets can Handel this pressure.
I have seen 120 psi city pressure , without a pressure reducing valve or regulator there will be problems or earlier failures.
Is it time to replace OR repair your regulator
It sounds like a repair could take care of your problems for less than a replacement

Comment: Thanks for your comments. In my case, I was curious as to what would cause such a large pressure drop when a faucet is opened, irrespective of which one it is (even one on the hose bib right after the PRV). The pressure gauges I have report a steady 68-70 static psi  (no water flow). The city supply pressure is well over a 100psi. Can a defective PRV lead to a large pressure drop when just one faucet is open while still maintaining a steady regulation with no water flow. BTW, my PRV sits on a 1.25” supply

Comment: If rust or scale get in the valve orifices that can limit the flow.  The regulator can still be doing its job of holding the pressure constant. So yes obstructions that limit the flow can be the issue

Comment: Thanks again. I appreciate your taking the time and effort to reply. I’ll look into replacing the PRV.

Comment: How did this work out? My reaction on reading this is that one would expect a large pressure drop under high flow and this could be absolutely normal. What is the size of the water meter? In Dallas the customer can select the size of the water meter for service from 5/8", 3/4", . . .

Comment: @jim Stewart a properly sized regulator will have very little affect on the flow. If you have a 1” main the most common size I have seen and 90 plus psi Supply with 3/4” plumbing there should be less than 3 psi drop if properly sized for the load. Most people just get a valve that fits the pipe and that is not the way to size the PRV.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if replacing the PRV reduced the pressure drop. Is there a standard  T fitting or set of fittings used to accurately determine the pressure drop in a pressurized water supply system? I would think that screwing a short arm T on any outside faucet with a pressure gauge on the right angle arm, then turning on the flow full on would give a huge pressure drop. How is this supposed to be done? I have no personal experience with testing pressurized water supply systems. In my area of Dallas TX we do not have PRVs. Whatever is in the water main is in our house.

Comment: @jim Stewart the the gauge is usually on the regulator outlet. most have a in and out then smaller 1/8 or 1/4” ports on each side connected to the outlet. A plug is put in the one you don’t use. Yes at the faucet there is a massive pressure drop because there are no restrictions. The valves or regulators are rated at a pressure and flow to get the flow at 60 psi it may take a 1-1/4” valve even though the supply is only 1” different brands have different orifices internally if it has 3/4 orifices or larger in the valve and a pressure more than 10 psi above your regulated value no drop at gauge.